# Supercompact cardinal above a measurable and fixed points of the ultrapower map

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Let $\kappa$ be a measurable cardinal and let $j:V\to M$ be the ultrapower map. Assume $\mu$ is a supercompact cardinal with $\mu>\kappa$. What can we say about $j(\mu)$? Is it true that $j(\mu)=\mu$? In general, can we say something about fixed points of $j$?

Comment: It is enough to prove that $\mu$ is the limit of $j$-fixed points, but that's easy since the set of fixed points below $\mu$ form a club.

Comment: Any inaccessible cardinal above $\kappa$ is fixed by $j$. In fact, unless I'm overlooking something, the same goes for any strong limit cardinal of cofinality $>\kappa$.